# Font Rendering Issue in Chrome - Google Web Fonts

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I am getting a weird Google Fonts rendering issue on Chrome. Here is what I mean:

**IE 10:**
[image]

**FireFox 36.0.4:**
[image]

**Chrome  41.0.2272.118 m:**
[image]

**Here is the close-up (Chrome):**

[image]

The font I am using is called "Playfair", and is available free on Google Fonts. Here is my **CSS / SCSS**:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic");

    .foo{
      font-family:$playfair;
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight:normal;
      color: $light_grey;          
      font-size:12px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the be the font hinting setting. I found several webfont generators that solve this problem by letting users select different hinting settings. If you are having the same issue, try this https://fontie.flowyapps.com/home

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried font-smoothing?

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Also, try changing:

```
font-weight: normal;
```

to:

```
font-weight: 400;
```

Comment: yep, tried all of that. Apparently, a lot of people are having this issue, and the only fix I found was to use `@font-face`, and make sure that Chrome and Opera render `svg` first. More details here: http://bit.ly/1yFVeXD